# My function returns before the data inside is processed to be returned

Tags: swift, iphone

I wrote a function that is supposed to get data from firebase database and then return them but the function returns before the data is even obtained .

I'm returning object called Review but it doesn't work like it should.
This is for my final school project and it's supposed to display reviews obtained from db but it doesn't work.

```swift
func createArrayOriginal() -> [Review] {
        var tempReviews: [Review] = []
        // Reference to database
        ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("reviews").child(shopId).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user value
            let values = ((snapshot.value) as? [String : AnyObject]!)!
            if values != nil {
                for item in values! {
                    let uid = item.value["reviewerUid"]!!
                    let text = item.value["reviewText"]!! as! String

                    self.ref.child("users").child("\(uid)").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        if value != nil {
                            let name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                            let imageURL = value?["imageURL"] as? String ?? ""

                            let image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOf: URL(string: imageURL)!)! as Data)
                            let review = Review(image: image!, name: name, reviewText: text)

                            print("review \(review.image) \(review.name) \(review.reviewText)")
                            tempReviews.append(review)
                            print("now \(tempReviews)")
                        } else {
                            // TODO: Alert something went wrong
                        }
                    }) { (error) in
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // TODO: Alert something went wrong
            }
        }) { (error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        // Only if static data works
        let data = Review(image: UIImage(named: "user")!, name: "Tom", reviewText:"Review Text")
        tempReviews.append(data)
        print("temp \(tempReviews)")
        // TODO: Why it returns before it's done??????????
        return tempReviews
    }
```

I expect the function to return after my data is set to the variable and not before

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. When exactly does your function return? Does it throw an error?

Comment: it is in a block. Block runs on a different thread. so it is returning you unprocessed data. Write your own completion block instead of returning.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/returning-a-value-from-asynchronous-code/